# Howto fix outdated backport repository in tails?

Tags: repository, dependencies, remmina, tails

i have basically the same problem as [Tails additional software unmet dependencies](https://superuser.com/questions/1401456/tails-additional-software-unmet-dependencies) , but cant comment right now.

I am running tails 3.12, live version, and adding additional software is not working after the restart, unlike before the update.

"[INFO] remmina : Depends: libssh-4 (>= 0.8.1) but 0.7.3-2+deb9u1 is to be installed "

I have exactly 3 versions of libssh, 2 of them meeting the dependencies,  but the last one is not. And that is the one from the backport repository, I needed for remmina.

Is there some way to fix that right away?

Or just wait, until the backport repo gets updated?

Thank you in advance